# Can Selenium monitor XHR requests

Tags: ajax, selenium

Is there any way in Selenium to monitor the XHR requests from an application. I want to create a test where the test clicks a button then checks to see if a correct Ajax request is made.

Edit, I am using PHP Unit if that matters.

Answer (score 7):

You can capture the network traffic with Selenium and then try get what you need for that

```
Selenium s = new DefaultSelenium(...);
s.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true");
s.open("http://www.google.com");
String traffic = s.captureNetworkTraffic("json");
```

And then do your asserts by finding what you want in the traffic.

Comment: is there a way to capture network traffic in selenium 2? i have tried to use browsermob-proxy but i am unable to find good documentation for it that supports python language.