# Monitor Chrome Network traffic (XHR packets)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking, phantomjs, protractor

I have a webapp to test. I got a test working with protractorJS that is clicking different buttons.
Some buttons do trigger a POST request, and the webapp is waiting for an answer from that point on. The answer can take up to 30 or 40 seconds to come in. If I look into the Chrome Developer tools, I see that the webapp sends GET packets to get the status every 2 seconds. The status can be `waiting`, `failed` or `successful`.

My Question is now:
How can I watch the network traffic and filter them that I know at which point the `successful` or `failed` status packet comes in?
I found PhantomJS [Network Monitoring](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html).

Basically I want to call a function after I clicked the button automatically with protractor, and this function should look into every packet that is coming in and should stop when it reads that the status is `successful`. If it takes more than 60 or 70 seconds the function should time out.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the button which triggers POST method you should start listening in a loop another endpoint (GET) every n seconds (you wrote that app does it every 2 seconds).

If status is `waiting` - keep going, if it's `failed` - raise an exception and fail the test, if it `successful` - pass the test or do whatever you want.

The loop will prevent you from timeout.

You need to consider whether you need to protect yourself from the infinite loop if e.g. worker which processes the task stops working. Then GET method may return `waiting`, the loop won't finish and the test won't stop.

Comment: Yes you're right, that would be the best way. But my question is how do I listen for a GET every two seconds? Theoretically it's easy: Listen in a loop and always check how the status is, until the status is `failed` or `successful` and then stop the loop. But HOW can I monitor/listen to all the incoming packages? I didn't write this webapp, I don't know how the inner functionalities work. I just want to monitor the traffic..

Comment: Hmm you can try those suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34950795/6331748 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103448/6331748